# disable underline when hovering on specific text inside li

Tags: css, html-lists, underline

I have these piece of code:

```
<nav role="navigation" class="toc">
  <span class="toc-title">Title:</span>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Some Text <textstyle>non-underlined text</textstyle></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I want that when hovering over the `<li>` element, only `Some Text` will be underlined, while the text inside `textstyle` element will not be underlined.

I have tried:

```
textstyle:hover, li a textstyle:hover, a > textstyle:hover{text-decoration: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put "Some Text" into a separate span:

```
<li><a href="#"><span class="underlined">Some Text</span><span> Some other text</span></a>
</li>
```

Then in CSS:

```
li:hover .underlined {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

You cannot partially remove an underline when it is added, likewise, you cannot add a partial underline (without a separate element).

Comment: Sorry, you gotta disable the default underline first. I'll edit

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS selector is wrong. What it actually does is select the `<textstyle>` when it is hovered.
Your new CSS code should be like this:

```
        li:hover > a{
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        li:hover > a > textstyle{
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is textstyle is not the element that is underlined, the anchor tag is so you can just do something like this (not sure what selector you want to use but here is one)

```css
li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation" class="toc">
  <span class="toc-title">Title:</span>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="">Some Text <textstyle>non-underlined text</textstyle></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
nav a, textstyle {
text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 background-image: linear-gradient(#000, #000);
 background-size: 100% 1px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 100%;
}
textstyle {
 background-image: linear-gradient(#fff, #fff);
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation" class="toc">
  <span class="toc-title">Title:</span>
  <ul>
<li><a href="">Some Text <textstyle>non-underlined text</textstyle></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

"I want that when hovering over the < li > element..." => hover goes on li element

```
    a {
    text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    li:hover .some-text-underlined {
        text-decoration: underline;
  
    }

<nav role="navigation" class="toc">
  <span class="toc-title">Title:</span>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="">
        <span class="some-text-underlined">Some Text </span>non-underlined text
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make the "Some text" be a `<textstyle>`, which means you HTML code will be:

```
<nav role="navigation" class="toc">
  <span class="toc-title">Title:</span>
  <ul>
    <li><a href=""><textstyle>Some Text</textstyle> non-underlined text</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Then you can use the following stylesheet to keep Some text underlined:

```
li:hover > a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

li:hover textstyle {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Snippet:

```css
li:hover > a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

li:hover textstyle {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<nav role="navigation" class="toc">
  <span class="toc-title">Title:</span>
  <ul>
    <li><a href=""><textstyle>Some Text</textstyle> non-underlined text</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```